# Get Start and End Time in Sql

Tags: sql, date, datetime, time, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three Shifts in my office.How i can get name of current running shift using Sql Query ?

Table Description is as given below

```
Id, Name, startTime, hours

1, Shift1, 7:00 am, 8

2, Shift2, 3:00 pm, 8

3, Shift3, 11:00 pm, 8
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what rdbms are you using? The answer depends on it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i am using Sql Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server I think:

```
select Id, Name, startTime, hours
from table 
where 
convert(time, getdate()) >= startTime
and convert(time, getdate()) < DATEADD(HH, hours, startTime)
```

**if** `startTime` column type is `time`.

---

**EDIT**

I strongly suggest to change the column to `Time`

If this cannot happen consider the solution below:

```
select convert( time, '6:00 am' )
-- result 06:00:00.0000000

select convert( time, '6:00 pm' )
-- result 18:00:00.0000000
```

So:

```
create view MyTableView as
select
    Id,
    Name,
    StartTime = convert( time, startTime ),
    EndTime = DATEADD(HH, hours, convert( time, startTime ) ),
    ShiftDuration = hours
from
    MyTable
```

**UPDATE** for 24h shift span

```
select
    Id,
    Name,
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    ShiftDuration
from 
    MyTableView 
where
    (
        ( StartTime < EndTime )
        and ( convert(time, getdate()) >= StartTime )
        and ( convert(time, getdate()) < EndTime )
    )
    or 
    (
        ( StartTime >= EndTime )
        and ( convert(time, getdate()) >= StartTime )
        and ( convert(time, getdate()) > EndTime )
    )
```

Comment: startTime column is string type

Comment: i changed time like this


1 Shift1 7:00 am 8 

2 Shift2 03:00 pm 8 

3 Shift3 11:00 pm 8 

When it's 11:15PM. It's showing Null result

Comment: In your original question you had 3 shifts that span through 18 hours on the same day. With the change you did, you extend the time span over two days for 24 hours. I think that the update should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's working perfectly from 07:00AM to 11:59PM... What about 12:00AM to 06:59AM ? It must be in Shift 3 as well

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a top-level question, so I'm going to give you a top-level answer, rather than writing the code for you, because that way you'll have the tools to solve other problems in future.

I would approach this in 3 stages:

1. Write a query that selects the *end time* of each shift based on the `startTime` and `hours` columns, i.e. "what time is X hours after time Y". The exact function to use depends which DBMS you use (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, SQLite, etc), but is likely to be called something like `date_add`.
2. Find out how to get the current time in your DBMS (e.g. `now()`, `getdate()`, `CURRENT_TIME`)
3. Write a `WHERE` clause that returns rows where a time is between two other times. (Hint: `BETWEEN` is a keyword in SQL.) Start simple with something you know will always be true, like "2:00 is between 1:00 and 3:00".

Put these together, and you can build the query you wanted: select rows where the current time is between the `startTime` and the calculated end time.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select *
from (
  select id, name, start_time, start_time + interval '1' hour * hours as end_Time
  from shifts
) t
where current_time between start_time and end_time;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5428/1

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2008 R2